# Spontaneous emission in a system with multiple sublevels

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have been trying to compose proper rate equations for density matrix of a 2 level system with multiple magnetic sublevels, and I have run into difficulty with including spontaneous emission terms in the model.

Say, I want to write rate equations for a 2 level system: in ground state $J_g=\frac{3}{2}$ (4 magnetic sublevels), and in excited state $J_e=\frac{1}{2}$ (2 magnetic sublevels).

Edit:The transition $g-e$ is electric dipole allowed, therefore transitions from magnetic sublevels of $e$ to magnetic sublevels of $g$ can be treated as electric dipole transitions.

Decay rate of the excited state is $\gamma$.
[image]

As far as I understand, decay rate for all subleves $m_J$ of the excited state is the same, $\gamma$. Therefore rate equations for the excited state would be:

$\rho _{e1,e1} = \Delta \rho_{e1,e1}[t] - i \gamma \rho_{e1,e1}[t]$

$\rho_{e2,e2} = \Delta \rho_{e2,e2}[t] - i\gamma \rho_{e2,e2}[t]$

Now I need to properly include decay terms in rate equations for ground level. The decay rate $\gamma$ should be somehow distributed over the three possible decay channels for each excited sublevel (e1 and e2).

$\rho_{g1,g1} = i X_{e1} \gamma\rho_{e1,e1}[t]$

$\rho_{g2,g2} = i Y_{e1} \gamma\rho_{e1,e1}[t] + i X_{e1} \gamma\rho_{e2,e2}[t]$

$\rho_{g3,g3} = i Z_{e1} \gamma\rho_{e1,e1}[t] + i Y_{e2} \gamma\rho_{e2,e2}[t]$

$\rho_{g4,g4} = i Z_{e2} \gamma\rho_{e2,e2}[t]$

My question is: how do I calculate relative intensities of these decay channels (denoted X,Y,Z in the equations above)?

I assume that I should calculate the relative intensities using Wigner 3j-symbols in the following way:

$X_{e1} = (2 J_e +1)*\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3/2 & 1 & 1/2 \\
 3/2 & -1 & -1/2
\end{array}
\right)^2$,

Therefore I would get the following values:

$X_{e1}=\frac{1}{2}$, $Y_{e1}=\frac{1}{3}$, $Z_{e1}=\frac{1}{6}$

$X_{e2}=\frac{1}{6}$, $Y_{e2}=\frac{1}{3}$, $Z_{e2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Is my reasoning correct? If not, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I can't help with the theory.  But in practice the spontaneous decay of magnetic levels can usually be ignored.  (because it's so small.)  First it's a magnetic dipole transition which are weaker than electric dipole, and maybe more importantly the decay goes as the energy cubed.  So the very small energy of your typical magnetic transition makes the rate very small.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This is however not the case of magnetic dipole transitions. The transition between the two levels g and e is electric dipole transition (for example, e and g can be fine structure levels of an atom). I have updated the post to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Ahh, OK. I was very interested in this several years ago, when I was building an optical pumping apparatus.  I wanted to calculate the absorption probability for the various magnetic sub levels.  (There were old theory papers giving the answer, but I wanted to see it for myself.)  I got a copy of Condon and Shortley (Theory of atomic spectra), and then enlisted the help of a theorist friend... And just got lost in all the changes of basis and angular momentum states...